# Cause of exiftool error (minor: PreviewImage) and should I be worried?

Tags: jpeg, exiftool, thumbnail-preview

While sorting my images with

```
exiftool "-directory<EXIF:DateTimeOriginal" -d %Y%m%d -ext jpg .
```

for some of .JPGs exiftool reported an error

```
Warning: [minor] Error reading PreviewImage from file - ./P5030553.JPG
```

**What does it mean, and is this something one should be worried about with regards to potential future problems and with regards to integrity of images?**

Almost all images in question came from a smartphone camera and Olympus camera, with no problems during transfer or alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have need of the PreviewImage, it probably isn't worth worrying about.  Minor errors aren't necessarily a sign of image damage.  It could be that the camera isn't writing the image metadata exactly according to the specifications or that ExifTool doesn't deal with the peculiarities of that specific camera.  Given the huge range of cameras out there, both situations happen fairly frequently.

If you feel the need, you could head over to the [ExifTool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/) and post an example image.  Phil Harvey, the creator of ExifTool, is quite likely to take a look at the image and figure out what the problem is and if need be, will quickly update ExifTool to deal with it.

Comment: I keep convincing myself that must be the case, since my image collection has that error on many images that came to be through a 5 year period. It seems unlikely that they were all corrupted in the same manner, systematically on that exact tag? What is PreviewImage by the way, since the image previews and thumbnails work fine?

Comment: @Rook  PreviewImage is pretty much what is sounds like.  A jpg that is embedded in the image to allow programs aware of it to quickly show what the image looks like.  It is usually a bigger preview than ThumbnailImage and usually part of the makernotes for the brand of camera.   If you like, you can use the command `ExifTool -b -PreviewImage FILE >Preview.jpg` to extract the image and take a look at it.  May I ask what are the cameras that this happens on?  And what version of ExifTool you are using?

Comment: Thought as much, but how is a jpg embeeded in a jpg file (files that this happens on are all .JPGs)? The models in question were HTC Desire 300, Samsung S5, and Olympus SZ-31MR camera. exiftool -ver reports 10.00.

Comment: @Rook The JPEG format (technically JFIF) allows for a large amount of data to be in the file before the actual image.  This includes, but not limited to, blocks of data such as EXIF, XMP, Photoshop data (which may include IPTC data), and ICC color profiles. Many camera models include proprietary blocks, which ExifTool collectively calls MakerNotes.  These can include an embedded jpg, the PreviewImage. The Photoshop and the EXIF block can include an embedded jpeg, which is the ThumbnailImage. A simple image viewer can skip all this and go straight to rendering the image.

Comment: @Rook (cont) Regarding your images, are you using a program to import them off the cameras?  Or a program to do any sort of processing or editing of metadata?  I downloaded a few test images of the web and ran a variation of your command (swapped TestName for Directory) and didn't have that error pop up. That makes me wonder if something in your workflow is slightly changing the metadata in the images in some way. It's a minor error and I'm quite certain you can ignore it without consequences, but it does make me curious about what's happening.

Comment: No, at least I'm not aware of it. Most of the time I just use/used explorer (from whatever Windows I was using at the moment) to copy the images off the memory card, or Nokia's PC suite, but I'm certain that application just copied/moved the images to disk. I haven't run any further analysis whether the images that reported that error came from a specific device, but I'm in the process of sorting my image collection, and if I came upon any more I'll upload it somewhere and post the link.

Comment: ps Is there a way to check for this error without running the above mentioned command and moving the pictures around?

Comment: Try `Exiftool -if "$warning" -warning DIR`.  Add `-r` to recurse.  That command doesn't catch all errors, there are many that ExifTool can't detect without actually going through the file, but it should catch the PreviewImage error, since that showed up with just a move command, not one that would edit the data.

Comment: It reported, 
3 directories scanned
151 files failed condition
0 image files read
that is, the large majority of files failed condition. For some it reported: Warning: [minor] Unrecognized MakerNotes

Since a lot of those files have been in my image collection for a number of years, and worked without problems I think I will put it down to misinterpretation of how EXIF data is written in them or how exiftool is reading it. But once I sort it all out I'll try to isolate examples of each and then put it up on exiftool's forum, to aid in diagnosting the errors, should

Comment: Phil have the interest to do so? What do you think?

Comment: Sounds good.  Phil always seems interested in oddities that pop up and usually gets to them, and if need be, fixes ExifTool with amazing speed.